# How to drag and drop divs with jQuery without using jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I am trying to learn jQuery and i want to move divs with the class .drag. and not outside a div with the ID #siteHolder

I don't want to use jQuery UI at the moment.

Any tips and tutorials would be nice.

Comment: Why not look at the jQueryUI source code and see how they do it :)

Comment: This doesn't have a simple answer, and all of the functionality is already built in jQuery-ui.  Why don't you want to use it?

Answer (score 2):

You can manually implement it processing the mouse move and down events.

- On mouse down mark object as being
  dragged
- On mouse move calculate the
  offset from the last cursor position
  and move the dragged object but
  checking before that the new position
  is inside the container box.

You can get inspiration from the jquery ui code in case you need.

Answer (score 0):

ppDrag is a Drag&Drop plugin for jQuery, which mimics the interface of jQuery UI's Draggable. Currently supported is a small subset of its options, but the implementation is different (ppDrag focuses on performance).

The speed difference is more visible with slower CPU's. Also, due to JavaScript engine optimizations in the last generation browsers, the speed difference is less than with older browsers. For example, the difference is greater with Firefox 2 than with Firefox 3.

All major existing browsers are supported. This includes IE6/7, Firefox1/2/3, Opera, Konqueror, Safari, and probably others.

[Plug-In](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ppdrag)